# Using << operator to write to both a file and cout

Tags: c++, file, operator-overloading, cout

I'd like to overload << operator to write the value it takes to a file and cout. I have tried to do it with following code, but couldn't succeed it. It just writes the value to text file. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
void operator<<(std::ostream& os, const string& str)
{
    std::cout << str;
    os << str;
}

int main() {
    ofstream fl;
    fl.open("test.txt");
    fl << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "but couldn't succeed it."

Comment: Looks like inadvertent infinite recursion. What you want instead is a `ostream` with a `streambuffer` that transparently multiplexes to any number of other streams. There is no standard one.

Comment: Nearly a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16135370/179910.

Comment: Overloading operators for standard types is bad enough, but when that operator is already overloaded?

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll check the other topic out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a helper class and overload operators that takes care of streaming to two streams. Use the helper class instead of trying to override the standard library implementations of the overloaded `operator<<` functions.

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct MyStreamingHelper
{
    MyStreamingHelper(std::ostream& out1,
                      std::ostream& out2) : out1_(out1), out2_(out2) {}
    std::ostream& out1_;
    std::ostream& out2_;
};

template <typename T>
MyStreamingHelper& operator<<(MyStreamingHelper& h, T const& t)
{
   h.out1_ << t;
   h.out2_ << t;
   return h;
}

MyStreamingHelper& operator<<(MyStreamingHelper& h, std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&))
{
   h.out1_ << f;
   h.out2_ << f;
   return h;
}

int main()
{
   std::ofstream fl;
   fl.open("test.txt");
   MyStreamingHelper h(fl, std::cout);
   h << "!!!Hello World!!!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fails on std::flush or std::endl.. says: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'xamid::helper::MyStreamingHelper' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>').

Comment: @xamid, works for me on my desktop as well as at https://ideone.com/a4QszP.

Comment: I am using MinGW-w64 compiler on Windows 7, c++11.

Comment: @xamid, I don't know how to help you there. Good luck.

Comment: None of the approaches that I found on the internet worked for me. Most had bugs like stopping to write to file after flush, some did not compile. So I tried Boost (boost::iostreams::tee_device) and it works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to use it, you will find that, not unsurprisingly, the boost library has already done most of the hard work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/tee.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

typedef boost::iostreams::tee_device<std::ostream, std::ostream> teedev;
typedef boost::iostreams::stream<teedev, std::char_traits<typename std::ostream::char_type>, std::allocator< typename std::ostream::char_type > > tee_stream;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ofstream of;
    of.open( "test.txt" );

    teedev td( of, std::cout );
    tee_stream ts(td);

    ts << "!!!Hello World!!!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah sure, did't think of checking boost library. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To implement a full stream interface you should build a stream buffer and a stream:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <vector>

// BasicMultiStreamBuffer
// ============================================================================

template<class Char, class Traits = std::char_traits<Char>, class Allocator = std::allocator<Char> >
class BasicMultiStreamBuffer : public std::basic_stringbuf<Char, Traits, Allocator>
{
    // Types
    // =====

    private:
    typedef typename std::basic_stringbuf<Char, Traits> Base;

    public:
    typedef typename std::basic_streambuf<Char, Traits> buffer_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::char_type char_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::traits_type traits_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::int_type int_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::pos_type pos_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::off_type off_type;

    private:
    typedef typename std::vector<buffer_type*> container_type;

    public:
    typedef typename container_type::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename container_type::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename container_type::reference reference;
    typedef typename container_type::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename container_type::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename container_type::const_iterator const_iterator;


    // Construction/Destructiion
    // =========================

    public:
    BasicMultiStreamBuffer()
    {}

    BasicMultiStreamBuffer(buffer_type* a) {
        if(a) {
            m_buffers.reserve(1);
            m_buffers.push_back(a);
        }
    }

    template <typename Iterator>
    BasicMultiStreamBuffer(Iterator first, Iterator last)
    :   m_buffers(first, last)
    {}

    ~BasicMultiStreamBuffer() {
        sync();
    }


    private:
    BasicMultiStreamBuffer(BasicMultiStreamBuffer const&); // No Copy.
    BasicMultiStreamBuffer& operator=(BasicMultiStreamBuffer const&); // No Copy.


    // Capacity
    // ========

    public:
    bool empty() const { return m_buffers.empty(); }
    size_type size() const { return m_buffers.size(); }


    // Iterator
    // ========

    public:
    iterator begin() { return m_buffers.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return m_buffers.end(); }
    iterator end() { return m_buffers.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return m_buffers.end(); }


    // Modifiers
    // =========

    public:
    void insert(buffer_type* buffer) {
        if(buffer) m_buffers.push_back(buffer);
    }

    void erase(buffer_type* buffer) {
        iterator pos = this->begin();
        for( ; pos != this->end(); ++pos) {
            if(*pos == buffer) {
                m_buffers.erase(pos);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    // Synchronization
    // ===============

    protected:
    virtual int sync() {
        int result = 0;
        if( ! m_buffers.empty()) {
            char_type* p = this->pbase();
            std::streamsize n = this->pptr() - p;
            if(n) {
                const_iterator pos = m_buffers.begin();
                for( ; pos != m_buffers.end(); ++pos) {
                    std::streamoff offset = 0;
                    while(offset < n) {
                        int k = (*pos)->sputn(p + offset, n - offset);
                        if(0 <= k) offset += k;
                        else {
                            result = -1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if((*pos)->pubsync() == -1) result = -1;
                }
                this->setp(this->pbase(), this->epptr());
            }
        }
        if(Base::sync() == -1) result = -1;
        return result;
    }

    private:
    container_type m_buffers;
};

typedef BasicMultiStreamBuffer<char> OStreamBuffers;


// BasicMultiStream
// ============================================================================

template<class Char, class Traits = std::char_traits<Char>, class Allocator = std::allocator<Char> >
class BasicMultiStream : public std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>
{
    // Types
    // =====

    private:
    typedef std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits> Base;

    public:
    typedef BasicMultiStreamBuffer<Char, Traits, Allocator> multi_buffer;
    typedef std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits> stream_type;

    typedef typename multi_buffer::buffer_type buffer_type;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::char_type char_type;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::traits_type traits_type;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::int_type int_type;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::pos_type pos_type;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::off_type off_type;

    typedef typename multi_buffer::size_type size_type;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::reference reference;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename multi_buffer::const_iterator const_iterator;


    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    BasicMultiStream()
    :   Base(&m_buffer)
    {}
    BasicMultiStream(stream_type& stream)
    :   Base(&m_buffer), m_buffer(stream.rdbuf())
    {}

    template <typename StreamIterator>
    BasicMultiStream(StreamIterator& first, StreamIterator& last)
    :   Base(&m_buffer)
    {
        while(first != last) insert(*first++);
    }

    private:
    BasicMultiStream(const BasicMultiStream&); // No copy.
    const BasicMultiStream& operator = (const BasicMultiStream&); // No copy.

    // Capacity
    // ========

    public:
    bool empty() const { return m_buffer.empty(); }
    size_type size() const { return m_buffer.size(); }


    // Iterator
    // ========

    public:
    iterator begin() { return m_buffer.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return m_buffer.end(); }
    iterator end() { return m_buffer.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return m_buffer.end(); }


    // Modifiers
    // =========

    public:
    void insert(stream_type& stream) { m_buffer.insert(stream.rdbuf()); }
    void erase(stream_type& stream) { m_buffer.erase(stream.rdbuf()); }

    private:
    multi_buffer m_buffer;
};

typedef BasicMultiStream<char> MultiStream;


// Test
// =============================================================================

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    MultiStream out;
    out.insert(std::cout);
    out.insert(std::clog);
    out << "Hello\n";
}
```

Here, the output is buffered in a string stream buffer and synchronized to the destination streams.

Comment: Why so complicated?  And why inherit from `stringbuf`, when you can just as easily inherit from `streambuf` directly?

Comment: @JamesKanze The intention is to have an additional buffer (handling all formatted/unformatted) IO and synchronize (flush to) the other buffers. Also, the multi-stream can be passed as std::ostream& without loosing functionality.

Comment: But why the iterators and the container interface?  What does that have to do with a `streambuf`?  If you need some sort of synchronization, so that both destinations do there physical writes at the same time, _containing_ an `std::vector<char>` for the buffer, and then doing a `sync` on the two target streambufs when you transfer it to them, should do the trick.

Comment: When I use an ofstream with this, it just stops writing to its file after the first flush (and a short amout of time). But it only does it when I run the file anone (not via Eclipse). Do you know how to fix this? I use MinGW-w64 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

The function you've overloaded takes a left hand side of `std::ostream&` and a right hand side of `const std::string&`. This is how you called the function:

> ```c++
> fl << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
> ```

The left hand side matches perfectly, but the right hand side doesn't. The string you've passed is not an `std::string` but rather a object of type `char const*`. The custom overload you made isn't called even though there is a viable conversion from `char const*` to `const std::string&` because there is in fact a perfect match *elsewhere*.

The overload that is a perfect match is the overload found in namespace `std` which is signed as:

```c++
namespace std { // Simplification:
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, char const* str);
}
```

This is a better match because no conversion needs to be made on the matter of the right hand parameter. Another reason this works is because of something called ADL or [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). Normally you would have to explicitly qualify names or functions from other namespaces (like `std`) from outside of those namespaces, but when it comes to ADL, if the compiler can find a function which takes a class of user-defined type from that same namespace, calling said function will not require explicit qualification from outside that namespace. Therefore the above is equivalent to:

> ```c++
> std::operator<<(f1, "!!!Hello World!!!") << std::endl;
> ```

You can see this while using `std::getline()`. The following is well-formed even though we do not use `using namespace std` or `using std::getline`:

```c++
getline(std::cin, line);
```

Because `std::cin` is within the same namespace as the function `std::getline()`, you do not need to append `std::` to the function call.

So for your overload to be called, there has to be a better match. You can force this by creating a `std::string` explicitly:

> ```c++
> fl << std::string("!!!Hello World!!!") << endl;
> ```

Your overload is called and not the one in namespace `std` because overloads in the enclosing namespace are considered before outer ones like `std`. But not only is this non-intuitive, it will also cause other issues.

1. Your function needs to return the type `std::ostream&` instead of `void` and have a `return os` statement so that you can chain the `<< endl` expression.
2. Inside your function you're performing infinite recursion on the `os << str` line. There are a number of ways to solve this issue, the easiest being to do `os << str.c_str()` so that the `char const*` overload in namespace `std` gets called.

Your method isn't the best way to do this so for more complete and better solutions, look toward the other answers and comments in this thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, it's a lot more clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

It just writes the value to the text file because your operator<< method does not get called.

The operator<< should return a reference to the stream (ostream&) because otherwise << str << endl; would not work.

The other problem with your operator<< is that it could create an infinite loop since os << str; has the same signature than fl << "string";

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of doing this is to use a filtering streambuf,
which forwards to both of the target streambufs.  Something like
the following should do the trick:

```
class LoggingStreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* myPrinciple;
    std::ostream*   myOwner;
    std::filebuf    myLogging;
protected:
    int overflow( int ch ) override
    {
        myLogging->sputc( ch );
        return myPrinciple->sputc( ch );
    }
public:
    LoggingStreambuf( std::streambuf* principal, std::string const& logFileName )
        : myPrinciple( principal )
        , myOwner( nullptr )
        , myLogging( logFileName )
    {
    }

    LoggingStreambuf( std::ostream& principal, std::string const& logFileName )
        : myPrinciple( principal.rdbuf() )
        , myOwner( &principal )
        , myLogging( logFileName )
    {
        myOwner.rdbuf( this );
    }

    ~LoggingStreambuf()
    {
        if ( myOwner != nullptr ) {
            myOwner.rdbuf( myPrinciple );
        }
    }
};
```

(This particular code supposes that the file output is a log
file, a secondary output on which errors should be ignored.
Other error handling strategies can also be implemented, and of
course, there's no reason that you couldn't provide two
arbitrary `std::streambuf*`, and create a new `std::ostream`
outputting through an instance of the custom streambuf.)

To use this class, as it is written:

```
LoggingStreambuf logger( std::cout, "logfile.txt" );
//  And output to std::cout as usual...
```

More generally, of course: anytime you want to do something
special with regards to the data sink or source of a stream, you
implement a new `std::streambuf`, since this is the class which
handles sinking and sourcing of data for the streams.

Comment: Doesn't compile: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::filebuf {aka std::basic_filebuf<char>}' main.cpp /ProofTool
no matching function for call to 'std::basic_filebuf<char>::basic_filebuf(const string&)'
request for member 'rdbuf' in '((LoggingStreambuf*)this)->LoggingStreambuf::myOwner', which is of pointer type 'std::ostream* {aka std::basic_ostream<char>*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
request for member 'rdbuf' in '((LoggingStreambuf*)this)->LoggingStreambuf::myOwner', which is of pointer type 'std::ostream* {aka std::basic_ostream<char>*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)