# Log the Command Line in C++

Tags: c++, logging

I'm trying to make a script that utilizes the command line for displaying data, and I want to be able to log everything that outputs to the command line into a separate file.

I'm using fstream, iostream, and std namespace.  I just need to know how to reference the the command line CmdExample.exe and everything it's says to write it to a txt file.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "This is some text I want to reference when the program ends" << endl << "and write to a txt file.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typically you would do `CmdExample.exe > output.txt`.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413744/using-operator-to-write-to-both-a-file-and-cout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use output redirection. ie:

```
./a.out > my_output.txt
```

This will put everything that would've been output to the terminal into a new file, `my_output.txt` (or overwrite anything already in the file).

If you want things output by `cerr` as well, you can modify it to be:

```
./a.out 2>&1 > my_output.txt #push stderr -> stdout, then stdout -> my_output.txt
```

Likewise, you could also use [script](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html). To use script, you would do:

```
script my_output.txt #start the script to my_output.txt 
./a.out #run program
exit #end script
```

Comment: I guess I should probably start coding in a linux environment, then.

Comment: @Jones Crimson there are bash emulators for windows that you can work in that would work just fine.